# Which design approach should I take for creating this custom view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface

I'm trying to create a generic, reusable view, that looks like a lined notepad.  The way I decided to approach the problem (after a couple design iterations) is to create a custom view that is composed of a `UITextView` and a `UIView`.

When the user scrolls through lines of text I want the UIView to track the scroll direction.  **The key here is:** Within my custom view, I need to change the position of one subview in response to events in another subview.  Something needs to coordinate these changes...

Now, one approach I thought of taking was to use a MVC design pattern. A view controller could handle all events and move the subviews around accordingly.  This MVC could then be embedded in other MVCs.

Normally when using a MVC design pattern, a controller would handle user events and manipulate the model and view.  However, my custom view doesn't have a model - all I'm trying to do is have the view manage it's own subviews when a user does something like scroll.  It seems to me that the MVC design pattern isn't a good fit here for two reasons:

1. There isn't a model or logic that is specific to the program it's being used in.
2. It seems to me that the view should be responsible for handling user events that change how the view should appear.

... but I could be wrong, which is why I'm asking for help.  The question, for those who are more experienced than I and who may have done this many times before, is:

What type of design pattern is appropriate in this situation? MVC or...

Comment: You could buy a pre-made view. Here is one paid implementation: [DTNotePadViewController](http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtnotepadviewcontroller/).

Comment: Yup... that's pretty much what I'm trying to do.  Except, I'm more interested in learning how to approach designing the custom notepad view that this person created.  As far as saving notes, etc, I would create a view controller for that but I'm kind of lost on designing the custom lined note view and defining it's behavior.

Comment: I think his blog has some notes on it. Not sure what he kept private or public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a view to manage its own subviews? Then do that! So what if that pattern doesn't have a [TLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym)?

A typical approach is to implement `layoutSubviews` in your container view. Have it check its current state, or the state of the other views in the window (e.g. the `contentOffset` of a scroll view), and then set up its subviews appropriately. (Resize them, reposition them, etc.)

Just try to keep it fast, since it's likely that `layoutSubviews` will be called frequently.

Comment: Kurt - can you describe more by what you mean by 'container view'.  I guess what I'm getting at is, do you suggest to create a UIView subclass which does nothing but manage subviews that I add to it in `layoutSubviews`?  One more question:  would it be unreasonable to have this container view be a `UIScrollViewDelegate` so that I can get callbacks when the user scrolls? ... thanks for the help - I'm basically looking for common approaches to this problem so that I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You have the right idea, yes.  You may not even need to make the view be a `UIScrollViewDelegate` -- it's possible that the scroll view will invalidate layout via `setNeedsLayout` in such a way that your view's `layoutSubviews` will automatically get called. (If not, it's easy enough to call `setNeedsLayout` when you need to.) Give it a try and see.